ViewPager2 and TabLayout in android studio (Java)
im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxsYMeTMClU and the only change i did is that im using a fragment instead of an activity. I did every step the same except ofr two things (beside using a fragment instead of activity):

Using onCreateView method instead of onCreate

Use getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager


Any help would be appreciated, or if anyone has a working tutorial on how to make a slideshow with viewpager2 it would be great! (ideally with three dots indicator instead of tabs)
i have followed some tutorial but always have some errors or maybe just not well explained.

Oh my, i forgot to return "fragment" instead of null inside createFragment method in the adapter
